# find a horizontal speed $\frac{dx}{dt}$

Tags: calculus

A girl slides down a slide in the shape of the parabola $y=(x−1)^2$ for $0≤x≤1$. Her vertical speed is $\frac{dy}{dt}=−y(1−y)$. Find her horizontal speed $\frac{dx}{dt}$ when $y=\frac 12$.
I have found that $$\frac{dy}{dt}=2(x+1)\frac{dx}{dt}$$, since $\frac{dy}{dt}=−y(1−y)$ and $y=\frac 12$ I got $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac {-\frac 12(1-\frac 12)}{2(x+1)}$$, but what to do with x now?

Comment: You can use $y = \frac 12$ to find $x$ and substitute it in your expression for $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: so, i put known y in initial equation of parabola in order to find x? so i got $\frac{-1}{8( \sqrt \frac12+2)}$, does it seem correct?

Comment: you didn't differentiate well look at my answer

Comment: Yes, you put $y = \frac 12$ in the equation and solve it for $x$. You will get two solutions (because it is quadratic equation), but you can rule one out because $0\leq x \leq 1$. Your answer doesn't seem to be correct, it should be $\frac 1{4\sqrt 2}$, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the chain rule:

$$
\frac { dx }{ dt } \quad =\quad \frac { dx }{ dy } \frac { dy }{ dt } \\ \qquad \quad =\quad \frac { 1 }{ \frac { dy }{ dx }  } y(y-1)\\ \qquad \quad =\quad \frac { y(y-1) }{ 2(x-1) } \\ \frac { dx }{ dt } \quad =\quad \frac { y(y-1) }{ -2\sqrt { y }  } 
$$

And now all you have to do is substitute $y = \frac{1}{2}$ to get:

$$
\\ \frac { dx }{ dt } \quad =\quad \frac { \frac { 1 }{ 2 } (\frac { 1 }{ 2 } -1) }{ -2\sqrt { \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }  } \quad =\quad \frac { 1 }{ 4\sqrt { 2 }  } 
$$

Comment: $x-1 = -\sqrt{y}$ since $0 \le x \le 1$

Comment: Thanks Dylan for pointing that out ^^

Comment: Where does $|y| = x - 1$ come from?

Comment: there's no such thing in my answer ^^